Create a macro that allows to automatically paste in transpose mode and delete the selected copied rows
Requesting a VBA code for creating a macro that allows to automatically paste in transpose mode in a selected cell and delete the selected rows that have been copied.
The data is in the following manner

Ana I want the data:



Why selecting? You show two categories and process both of them. Why place them in a selected cell? Can't you establish where to place them (transposed)? For instance, in the first empty row (probably) of a different sheet? Don't you need to copy/transpose all existing? 2. It is also good to not show pictures! Editable content can be used by somebody wanted to help you. 3. Can you show us your attempt to solve the problem? Even if it does not work as you need... It is good to prove that you did some research and you do not simple ask somebody else to do your job...


Please, try using the next code. It assumes that the range to be processed exists in columns A:B, and in the first row there are headers. It will return starting from "M2", the same sheet. It can be easily adapted to return in a different sheet:
Sub copyTransposeDelete()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rng As Range, arr, arrIt, arrFin
  Dim i As Long, maxCol As Long, j As Long, dict As Object
  
  Set ws = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary sheet
  lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row on A:A column
  Set rng = ws.Range("A2:B" & lastR) 'the range to be processed/deleted
  
  arr = rng.Value2 'place the range in an array for faster processing (in memory)
  
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'set the necessary dictionary
  
  'load the dictionary with unique keys and all items for the same key:
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr) 'iterate between the array rows:
    If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then       'if dictionary key does not exist, create it
        dict.Add arr(i, 1), Array(arr(i, 2)) 'create it, with B:B value in an array
    Else                                     'if it exists:
        arrIt = dict(arr(i, 1))              'place the item in an array to update it
        ReDim Preserve arrIt(UBound(arrIt) + 1) 'increase the number of elements by one, preserving existig
        arrIt(UBound(arrIt)) = arr(i, 2)        'load the value from B:B in the last array element
        dict(arr(i, 1)) = arrIt                 'place back the updated array as item
        If maxCol < UBound(arrIt) + 1 Then maxCol = UBound(arrIt) + 1 'determine maximum necessary number of columns
    End If
  Next i
  
  If maxCol = 0 Then maxCol = 1 'if only one element (1D array), make it 1 (2D array)
  ReDim arrFin(1 To dict.count, 1 To maxCol + 1) 'redim the final array to keep all possible columns
  For i = 0 To dict.count - 1   'iterate between the dictionary elements
    arrFin(i + 1, 1) = dict.keys()(i)            'place the key in the first column
    For j = 0 To UBound(dict.Items()(i))
        arrFin(i + 1, j + 2) = dict.Items()(i)(j) 'place each element of item array in its column
    Next j
  Next i
  
  'drop the final array content, at once
  ws.Range("M2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value2 = arrFin
  
  'delete the used range (rng)
  rng.Select 'it now only selects it. if the code works as you need you have to
             'replace Select with Clear
End Sub

It now only selects the used range to be processed. As commented, if you are satisfied by the code return, you have to replace Selecgt with Clear.
If you really need to process only slices from A:B column obtained by manual selection you should only replace Set rng = ws.Range("A2:B" & lastR) with Set rng = Selection.
I tried commenting all the lines. If still something not clear enough, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.
And as general observation, I answered your question because you are new, not knowing very well the community customs. It is good to show some personal interest in solving the problem by your own and asking only after you could not solve the problem. Proving your own effort... This shouldn't be a must, but it is good to be done. Otherwise, our enthusiasm in helping you will not be so high...
